# Getting error message when loading an .xlsx file?

Tags: r

I am not sure why this is happening. I am trying to load about 180 .xlsx files using the xlsx package. I have run though code that i thought would load all the files (different names but same format) and extract 3 rows from each file. See below:

```
f <- list.files("./") 

dat = lapply(f, function(i){
     x = read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex=1, sheetName=NULL, startRow=127,
     endRow=130, as.data.frame=TRUE, header=T)

# You may want to add a column to say which file they're from

     x$file = i

# Return your data

     x
     })
```

I get the following error

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl, : 
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

I have updated JAVA on my MAC but that didnt work.

Any suggestions anyone?

Anoop

Comment: Can you try the `readxl` package? It has fewer dependencies so might not run into this error.

Comment: Another non-java option is `openxlsx`.

Comment: I've received the same error. I think it might be a problem with the `xlsx` package.

Comment: What happens, if you try to load the first file manually? If this is ok, try the second one. If both are ok, do the loop over these two files only. I think that is a way to decide where the problem really is.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are trying to read may not be an xlsx file ..
I got the same error when reading a file of xlsx format.
When I tried to read the same file with read.csv(), it worked . So it shows that the file I was trying to read is not in xlsx format.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are loading a file that was already opened. The file would have the same extension in the specified directory.